# receive get parameters in url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, get, request

I make a `ul` menu in wordpress like this:

```
<li><a href="<?php get_page_link(); ?>?show=game" class="android-prim-menu-active">بازی ها</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php get_page_link(); ?>?show=app">app</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php get_page_link(); ?>?show=request">request</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php get_page_link(); ?>?show=report">report</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?php get_page_link(); ?>?show=last">live</a></li>
```

Now, every of these links send a `GET` request to current page and I want to handle content with received values from `GET` request.

How do i use `GET` method in wordpress? Can I use `$_GET["show"]` and receive my values?

Thanks...

Comment: Well, have you tried it?

Comment: yes, it works. but i want to do it in a wordpress standard way!

Comment: If the code works and you just want to know if there is a better way, I would recommend you to post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
  $_GET["show"]
  method and you can 
  echo $_GET["show"] 
  this and you will get the value
```